# Hapi set cookie on post request

Tags: node.js, cookies, hapi.js

I am using Hapi.js last version, and i am trying to implement login system with help of cookies, but problem is when i am opening `/auth` route directly in browser i am getting `set-cookie` header, but when i send post request, i still recieve `ok` in response and 201 code, but no cookie header exist.

```
server.state('auth', {
    ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    isSecure: false,
    isHttpOnly: false,
    encoding: 'base64json',
    clearInvalid: false,
    strictHeader: true,
});

server.route({
    method: ['POST', 'GET'],
    path: '/auth',
    handler: (request, h) => {
        return h
            .response({status: 'ok'})
            .state('auth', {id: 1337})
            .code(201);
    },
});
```

Comment: did you figure out the solution for this one?